# Is there a way to typecheck just few lines in a file with flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

When we put `// @flow`, it typecheck all the file.
How tell flow that just few lines need to typecheck in a file ? 
Is it possible ?

Comment: Why is it a problem that flow checks the whole file? Do you need this for debugging? Do you get false-positives? Apparently it is possible to disable flow for certain lines, but not for line blocks: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/740

Comment: Thank's ! That's what I was looking for !